# What's the best JS replacement of frameset in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a internal management system with a menu in the left and different forms in the right. On click of item in menu, right block should reload corresponding page. `<frameset>` can do this, but it's ancient. I want to know the best JS or Jquery replace of the `<frameset>` functionality.

Comment: The alternative is semantic HTML and AJAX.

Comment: Do you wan't to load the page every time the button is clicked?

Comment: I want no reload every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand you should use load in jQuery.

```
$('.menuButton').on('click', function(){
   $('#resultPanel').load('thePageYouNeed.html');
});
```

And if you didn't want the load them every time you can load multiple
`<div>`'s in the result panel, then just show then one you need when you need it.

## [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)